# Django - Gunicorn - shutdown and reboot ubuntu

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, gunicorn

I've built an application in Django.
While testing I've used manage.py runserver commando. Now when I am done, I've transferred the Django application to Gunicorn.
All works fine, except one thing:
The web application has an option to shutdown and reboot the Ubuntu server machine (for logged in admin users).
When running the application using manage.py runserver, it had permissions to do it.

But now with gunicorn, it doesn't. However it's maybe not fully save, I now the risks and want to do it.

Does anyone have an option to shutdown and reboot the Ubuntu machine using the Django application?

With manage.py runserver I've used:

```
cmd = "sleep 5 && reboot"
result = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
```

Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

You're wanting to grant additional permissions to the user account that's used to run your web server. I would be very hesitant to do that, but if you want to, I would only grant the specific reboot permission to it. Here's an answer that may help you do that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465236

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (had to wait for someone to test it). This seems not to work for me. When I add the sudo permission, it still gives me the error Failed to set wall message ignoring interactive authentication required.